# Drop table in pre-copy script

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

[image: sink-configuration]

I am trying to parameterize the pre-copy script to DROP existing tables of the same schema and table name from a SQL Server sink. I have tried variations of the above, what's the correct syntax to use the dataset properties in the pre-copy script?

Additionally, is there a good resource on using the dynamic content in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing other questions with parameterized query steps, the parameters are incorrectly prefixed, the following was executed successfully:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}.@{item().table_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @{item().destination.schema}.@{item().destination.table}
```

Tested it and it works now.

Comment: Almost…? What do you mean?